# Wordpress Custom Built Role access to use taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress

Developing Wordpress Site, with custom post types and taxonomies,

Have created a role where this user can only edit their own posts on 1 custom post type (not on any other posts).

This works fine and is achieved by the code below, the issue is while this user can see the taxonomies associated with this post type,

the user cannot add these taxonomies to the custom post (tick box is greyed out)

I know changing edit post to true will allow this however can't do that as it then gives the user access to the other post types on the site

any help ideas appreciated thanks

```
add_role('psp_project_manager',
        'Project Manager',
        array(
            'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
            'edit_posts' => false,
            'delete_posts' => false,
            'publish_posts' => false,
            'upload_files' => true,
        )
    );
}

function psp_add_role_caps() {

    // Add the roles you'd like to administer the custom post types

    $roles = array('psp_project_manager');

    // Loop through each role and assign capabilities
    foreach($roles as $the_role) {

         if ( get_role( $the_role ) ) {

             $role = get_role($the_role);

             $role->add_cap( 'read' );
             $role->add_cap( 'read_psp_project');
             $role->add_cap( 'read_private_psp_projects' );
             //$role->remove_cap( 'edit_others_psp_project' ); 
             //$role->remove_cap( 'edit_others_psp_projects' ); 
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_psp_project' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_psp_projects'  );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_psp_project' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_psp_projects' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_private_psp_project' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_private_psp_projects'  );

             //$role->add_cap( 'edit_others_psp_projects' );
             //$role->add_cap( 'edit_published_psp_projects' );
             $role->add_cap( 'publish_psp_project' );
             $role->add_cap( 'publish_psp_projects' );
             $role->remove_cap( 'delete_others_psp_projects' );
             //$role->add_cap( 'delete_private_psp_projects' );
             $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_psp_projects' );
        }
    }
}
```